# Git setup in RubyMine VCS for windows 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

I am new in ruby on rails. i want to save my demo projects on github can any one help me to setup git in RubyMine IDE. Step by Step Help will be appreciated. I tried every link but didnt help out.
I tried following link.
http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/using-git-integration.html

Answer (score 0):

I'll give it a shot and try to break down that tutorial into steps.

First, make sure you have git installed on your machine, if not there is a [great tutorial to install git on windows by Github](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git#platform-windows).

This is just one way to do it, but in a general overview

First [create a local git repository](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/setting-up-a-local-git-repository.html) with RubyMine

Next, [add untracked files to the git repository](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/adding-files-to-a-local-git-repository.html) with RubyMine

After then, [commit changes to the git repository](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/committing-changes-to-a-local-git-repository.html) with RubyMine

Then, you create a repository on Github and [push to your remote repository on Github](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/pushing-changes-to-the-upstream-%28git-push%29.html) with RubyMine

You can also do all of these things from the Git Bash command line or Github for Windows GUI as well.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your greate help i tried it.... but at the push i got this error --> fatal: https://github.com/asadalibhatti@hotmail.com/Depot1.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?

Comment: Try this, open your Git Bash in Windows, go to the root of your RubyMine rails project and `git remote set-url git@github.com/(YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME)/(YOUR_GITHUB_REPO).git` and that should also connect your RubyMine rails project to your github repository you created and then restart RubyMine and try pushing again, hope this helps